# Grails Message source bug in Service

Tags: rest, grails, service

I am in trouble with one point in Grails 3.3.11 and I need help.

I am developing a rest-api in grails 3.3.11, but I can't use message source for i18n in service. It only works in my controller.

```
message = messageSource.getMessage('documentProperties.notFound', [partId,jsonRequestDoc.get("typeId")] as Object[], LocaleContextHolder.locale)
```

When I do that above, I receive this in service.

```
Cannot invoke method getMessage() on null object
```

My messageSource is defined in the beginning of my service class as below:

```
 @Autowired
 def messageSource
```

In order to resolve this, I manually created a service constructor which receives message source from the controller.

```
class CmbIdService {
 public CmbIdService(def messageSource){
        this.messageSource = messageSource
    }
}

It was working as expected, but when I started running my integration tests, I noticed that Grails did not know how to instantiate my service considering the presence of the constructor. This the message I receive when I run the Grails Integration tests.

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cmbIdService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Object' available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates... continue.
```

Could anyone help me. I don't know what to do. I need to use message source for internacionalization. And I need to do that in service, not only in the controller. And my tests need to continue working.

Thanks!

Alfredo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this...

```
class CmbIdService {
 public CmbIdService(def messageSource){
        this.messageSource = messageSource
    }
}
```

Do this...

```
class CmbIdService {
    def messageSource
}
```

If that class is defined in `grails-app/services/[whatever your package is]/CmbIdService.groovy`, then an instance will automatically be created for you, added to the application context as a bean, and that instance will be subjected to autowire-by-name.

**EDIT**

Comments below suggest that the OP is still getting an NPE.  I have provided a working example at https://github.com/jeffbrown/dnunesmessagesource.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/dnunesmessagesource/blob/d05fe05a6679351fd5ff6779aebf30b6e6f3790d/grails-app/services/dnunesmessagesource/CmbIdService.groovy

```
package dnunesmessagesource

import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder

class CmbIdService {
    def messageSource

    String getCustomMessage() {
        messageSource.getMessage('my.custom.message', [] as Object[], LocaleContextHolder.locale)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/dnunesmessagesource/blob/d05fe05a6679351fd5ff6779aebf30b6e6f3790d/grails-app/controllers/dnunesmessagesource/DemoController.groovy

```
package dnunesmessagesource


class DemoController {
    CmbIdService cmbIdService
    
    def index() {
        String message = cmbIdService.customMessage
        [customMessage: message]
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/dnunesmessagesource/blob/d05fe05a6679351fd5ff6779aebf30b6e6f3790d/grails-app/i18n/dnunes.properties

```
my.custom.message=This Is My Custom Message
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/dnunesmessagesource/blob/d05fe05a6679351fd5ff6779aebf30b6e6f3790d/grails-app/views/demo/index.gson

```
model {
    String customMessage
}

json {
    message customMessage
}
```

That all appears to work as designed.

```
$ http :8080/demo
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 31 Mar 2021 18:31:37 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Application-Context: application:development

{
    "message": "This Is My Custom Message"
}
```

Comment: It does not work when I run the app and request the endpoint.

Comment: Cannot invoke method getMessage() on null object

Comment: "Cannot invoke method getMessage() on null object" - Are you creating an instance of `CmbIdService` using `new CmbIdService()`?

Comment: Yes, I am.  new CmbIdService().saveDocument(params.partId,jsonRequestDoc)

Comment: "Yes, I am. new CmbIdService()" - That is the problem.  You should not create an instance of the class yourself.  If you do, it will not be subjected to dependency injection, which is why you are getting a `NullPointerException`.  Let the DI container inject the instance for you, as in the example I created.

Comment: @DNunes If you can share a sample repo like the one that I created for you and configure that app to demonstrate the problem you are having, I would be happy to look at it and send a PR to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for the delay. You help was cool, now the api is working as expected. My repo is private, so I cannot share it, but the problem is solved because of your tip. Really thanks!